# Unable to set segmentedControl back to no index selected

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, ios13

I'm using iOS 13 Beta, my UISelectedControl start with no index selected (-1)

`"selectedSegmentIndex" = -1`

After selecting any option, I want to reset on clic of a button like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedC: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func didTapDeselectButton(_ sender: Any) {
    segmentedC.selectedSegmentIndex = -1

}
```

What I observe is that the segmentedControl is behaving strangely, element prove me that the system understood and deactivated it :

- reappearing of the little gray separator bar between options
- selected option text becoming regular instead of bold again

but the white pellet isn't hidden

[Video of the phenomenon](https://giphy.com/gifs/Su0Zg1qgR1VcVf7ssw/html5)

Comment: Don’t use a hard coded value of -1. There is s provided constant for “no selected index”. You need to use that constant.

Comment: same behavior with the constant, thank you for pointing this out rmaddy

Answer (score 1):

Because you use a beta version of iOS13 you should file bug report using the native Feedback Assistant app for iOS and Mac. [Introducing Feedback Assistant for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)

For issues not mentioned in release notes, file bugs through Apple Bug Reporter.
When filing a bug, please include the full version number in the bug title and in the description. This looks like “10.14 (18Axxxx).” You can find the full version number by choosing About This Mac from the Apple Menu. In the window that appears, click on “Version 10.14” displayed beneath “macOS” to show the full version including the part that is in parentheses.